# Django periodic task in period of time

Tags: django, django-admin, celery, scheduled-tasks, periodic-task

I want to make complex tasks that let me control when the task will be started, when it will be finished, when it can repeated
Example: I want to create task, it's description **call 10 of clients** and this task will be assigned to **X user** and the quantity of this task will be **10** but I want this task will start from **1/1/2018** and it will be finished in **30/12/2018** and the repeat of this task will be **weekly**

**Hint**: meaning of the repeat, each week I will get the real quantity of the user that's done divided by the quantity of the task and make the quantity of the user is zero in the next week and so on.
In details, The X user will start work on Saturday with the target of calling 10 clients by the end of the week, at the end of the week I will calculate the number of clients he called him and I will start again from scratch in the next week with the new task and so on.

what is the best way to do that in Django? is there any way to do that with Celery? if can I do that is there any way to do that in Django Admin?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your relevant code so we can start from there?

Comment: Are you looking for cronjobs?

Comment: if I can do this with cronjobs, it will be ok